# How do I interpret an Intel Realsense camera depth map in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, intel, realsense

I was able to view and capture the image from the depth stream in MATLAB (using the webcam from the Hardware Support Package) from an F200 Intel Realsense camera. However, it does not look the same way as it does in the Camera Explorer.
What I see from MATLAB -

[image: Depth Map]

I have also linked [Depth.mat](https://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/342826-139279/Depth.mat.zip) that contains the image in the variable "D".

The image is returned as a 3 dimensional array of uint8. I assumed that the depth stream is a larger number that is broken in bits in each plane and tried bitshifting each plane and adding it to the next while taking care of the datatypes. Then displayed it using imagesc, but did not get a proper depth image.

How do I properly interpret this image? Or, is there an alternate way to capture images in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ?

Comment: It would be helpful if there was a baseline photo to compare with the depth image